# How to get data from a nested div

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following html example

```
<div class="list">
<div class="Teamlist">
<div class="Teamcontainer OPEN" dataid="73592"><div>
</div>
</div>
```

i am trying to get the dataid from teamcontainer but it keeps on returning undefined.This is what i tried

```
if ($this.hasClass("list") && $this.hasClass("Teamlist") && $this.hasClass("Teamcontainer")) {

                    var ID = $this.parents(".Teamcontainer").attr("dataid");

 }
```

the above id just returns undefined. how do i get ID=73592? what am i doing wrong

Comment: `$this.hasClass("list") && $this.hasClass("Teamlist")` – how could that ever be true? You do not have a single element there that has _both_ those classes.

Comment: $this contains the class list attributes

Comment: Don’t know what that is supposed to mean. (`hasClass` works on element collections, not sure what “the class list attributes” would even be supposed here.) Show a _proper_ [mre], please.

Comment: following your code, It's very simple. `var ID = $(".list.Teamlist.Teamcontainer").attr("dataid");`

Answer (score 0):

Just use jquery selector like this:

```
var ID = $(".list .Teamlist .Teamcontainer").attr("dataid");
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in 2 ways. first using attr as Michal answered above  and 2nd if you change your dataid to data-id,, here are both the examples.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //first way by Attr

  var dataID = $(".list .Teamlist .Teamcontainer").attr("dataid"); 
  console.log(dataID);


  // second using data, but for this you need to change your attribut to data-id
  var dataId = $(".list .Teamlist .Teamcontainer.OPEN").data("id"); 
  console.log(dataId);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
<div class="Teamlist">
<div class="Teamcontainer" dataid="73592"><div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="list">
<div class="Teamlist">
<div class="Teamcontainer OPEN" data-id="73592"><div>
</div>
</div>
```